# How to setup default navigation drawer and select different fragments?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am novice developer and I'm integrating default (ready-made) Navigation drawer in my app with androidx. I'm having problem with navigating fragments as it doesn't work when I click on the drawer menu items. There are two fragments which are linked with their id's and set onClick listener, but it doesn't work. It just shows the main fragment but doesn't navigate to other fragments.

I'm not familiar with default functions like `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` and `onSupportNavigateUp()` which are created by itself when I created the default drawer activity, so I just comment these functions and by following a tutorial I implement the `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` which gives me `onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)` function where I wrote the code for navigate fragments. But it doesn't worked and when I debug, it shows that the `onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)` is not called.

```
public class FindBarber extends AppCompatActivity implements.

NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
Toolbar toolbar;
DrawerLayout drawer;
NavigationView navigationView;
int OPEN, CLOSE;


 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_barber);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, OPEN, CLOSE);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();


    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
  /*  mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_profile, R.id.nav_kutit_wallet,
            R.id.nav_terms_of_use, R.id.nav_rate_the_app, R.id.nav_contact_us)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();*/
   /* NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.content_frame);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);*/

       FragmentManager fmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
       fmanager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new GMap()).commit();


}

/*@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.find_barber, menu);
    return true;
}
*/
 // @Override
/* public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    *//*NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.content_frame);*//*
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}*/

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new GMap()).commit();
            break;

        case R.id.nav_profile:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new Profile()).commit();
            break;
    }
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

There is no error message nor any app crash occurs. When I click navigation drawer item for navigating any fragment, it doesn't show anything except the main default fragment which I show in screen.

Answer (score 0):

Call **loadFragment(new Fragment(),"My Fragment")**  onNavigationItemSelected

```
public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment, String title_name){  
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();  
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.customer_container,fragment,title_name);
 fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
 }
```

Comment: Nothing happened. It didn't help but anyway thanks for your support.

Comment: public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment){
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
        transaction.commit();
    }

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                loadFragment(new GMap());
                break;

            case R.id.nav_profile:
                loadFragment(new Profile());
                break;
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below line :

```
navigationView.getMenu().performIdentifierAction(R.id.posts, 0);
```